# Azure ML Python SDK Installation Issue

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

- **Environment**: Windows 10 64bit
- **Issue**: Can successfully install the `azureml-core`, `azureml-widgets`, `azureml-mlflow` with `1.35.0` version. However, when I tried to install the `azureml-pipeline` package with the following command

  > `pip install azureml-pipeline`

  It will remove all the current `1.35.0` versions of `azureml-core` and replace with a older version as `1.0.85` as shown

```
...
  Attempting uninstall: ruamel.yaml
    Found existing installation: ruamel.yaml 0.17.16
    Uninstalling ruamel.yaml-0.17.16:
      Successfully uninstalled ruamel.yaml-0.17.16
  Attempting uninstall: azure-mgmt-resource
    Found existing installation: azure-mgmt-resource 13.0.0
    Uninstalling azure-mgmt-resource-13.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled azure-mgmt-resource-13.0.0
  Attempting uninstall: azureml-core
    Found existing installation: azureml-core 1.35.0
    Uninstalling azureml-core-1.35.0:
      Successfully uninstalled azureml-core-1.35.0
  Attempting uninstall: azureml-pipeline-core
    Found existing installation: azureml-pipeline-core 1.35.0
    Uninstalling azureml-pipeline-core-1.35.0:
      Successfully uninstalled azureml-pipeline-core-1.35.0
Successfully installed azure-mgmt-resource-8.0.1 azureml-core-1.0.8585 azureml-telemetry-1.0.85.2 azureml-train-core-1.0.85
```

In addition, I checked the `azureml-pipeline` version and there has `1.35.0` as shown

```
azureml-pipeline (1.35.0)
Available versions: 1.35.0, 1.34.0, 1.33.0, 1.32.0, 1.31.0, 1.30.0, 1.29.0, 1.28.0, 1.27.0, 1.26.0, 1.25.0, 1.24.0, 1.23.0, 1.22.0, 1.21.0, 1.20.0, 1.19.0, 1.18.0, 1.17.0, 1.16.0, 1.15.0, 1.14.0, 1.13.0, 1.12.0, 1.11.0, 1.10.0, 1.9.0, 1.8.0, 1.7.0, 1.6.0, 1.5.0, 1.4.0, 1.3.0, 1.2.0, 1.1.5, 1.0.85, 1.0.83, 1.0.81, 1.0.79, 1.0.76, 1.0.74, 1.0.72, 1.0.69, 1.0.65, 1.0.62, 1.0.60, 1.0.57, 1.0.55, 1.0.53, 1.0.48, 1.0.45, 1.0.43, 1.0.41, 1.0.39, 1.0.33, 1.0.30, 1.0.23, 1.0.21, 1.0.18, 1.0.17, 1.0.15, 1.0.10, 1.0.8, 1.0.6, 1.0.2, 0.1.80, 0.1.74, 0.1.68, 0.1.65, 0.1.59, 0.1.58, 0.1.57
```

and if I specify the version of as

> `pip install azureml-pipeline==1.35.0`

it shows the error as shown:

```
Requirement already satisfied: azureml-core~=1.35.0 in c:\essential_software\anaconda3\envs\pytorch-env\lib\site-packages (from azureml-pipeline-core~=1.35.0->azureml-pipeline==1.35.0) (1.35.0)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of azureml-pipeline-core to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of azureml-pipeline to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement azureml-train-automl-client~=1.35.0 (from azureml-pipeline-steps) (from versions: 1.0rc83, 1.0rc85, 1.0.76, 1.0.79, 1.0.81, 1.0.81.1, 1.0.83, 1.0.85, 1.0.85.1, 1.0.85.2, 1.0.85.3, 1.0.85.4, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.1rc0, 1.1.2rc0, 1.1.5, 1.1.5.1, 1.1.5.2, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 
1.5.0.post1, 1.6.0, 1.6.0.post1, 1.7.0, 1.7.0.post1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.9.0.post1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.11.0.post1, 1.12.0, 1.12.0.post1, 1.12.0.post2, 1.13.0, 1.13.0.post1, 
1.13.0.post2, 1.14.0, 1.14.0.post1, 1.15.0, 1.15.0.post1, 1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.18.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for azureml-train-automl-client~=1.35.0
```

- **Replicate the issue**:

  > `pip install azureml-core`
  > `pip install azureml-pipeline`

Comment: I found out the reason. My current python version ```3.9.5``` does not support the ```azureml-pipeline```. When I downgrade the python to ```<= 3.8.12```, I can install everything without any problem.